# How to combine range a-z with 0-9

Tags: php, foreach, range

I have a foreach:

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo "<a href=\"#$char\">$char</a>";
}
```

How do I combine this and make this search through 0-9 first?

Thanks!

Comment: @Scopey's answer is best, but at a minimum why didn't you loop thru `range(0, 9)` and then loop thru `range('A', 'Z')`???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach(array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'Z')) as $char) {
    echo $char;
}
```

[Relevant ideone](https://ideone.com/AQRdCN)

Comment: `array_merge(range(0, 9), range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'))` to include lowercase as well.